# Finding relative upload path for my wicket project

Tags: java, web, wicket

I need to make it possible to upload pictures to the /picture folder on my  webserver. The problem is that I do not know how to find the path to copy files to. I have studied the icket examples, but they use;

```
uploadFolder = new Folder(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"), 
               "wicket-uploads");
```

to find the correct folder to copy files to. What I need is the path to my html files so that I can add the /picture folder to that path. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [getRealPath(...) method of the ServletContext](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29)

```
String realPath = context.getRealPath("pictures");
```

To get the ServletContext use the WebApplication class that is accessible from all your pages:

```
ServletContext context = ((WebApplication) getApplication()).getServletContext();
```

Comment: I get an error saying: can not find symbol: Symbol metod getApplication(). I have importeded the following librarie: import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import org.apache.wicket.protocol.http.WebApplication;

Comment: getApplication() is a method of Component. It is available on every class extending Component: http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/Component.html#getApplication()

Comment: Solved it. It could not be in the application.java file. Moved it to my "copy" file and it works. Thanks :-)